# activating load more function for php

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to limit a text to 500 characters and add load more button

I succeeded in this but I have difficulties in the last step

now this is a code I tool from another question and edit it to suit my code

what I want now is to make the "load more" button shows the remaining post text, not opening a new window or going to the page header (the same as see more in facebook)

please help

```
$string = strip_tags($body);
if (strlen($string) > 500) {
    $stringCut = substr($string, 0, 500);
    $endPoint = strrpos($stringCut, ' ');
    $string = $endPoint? substr($stringCut, 0, $endPoint) : substr($stringCut, 0);
    $string .= '... <a href="/this/story">Read More</a>';
}
```

Comment: You could hide the remaining content using CSS and change the visibility when the button/link is clicked. You could use ajax to fetch the remaining content

Comment: I think the problem here is you handle displaying more text via backend / server not at client side. Yuu could also echo the full text and hide it intial then show it via css or js (so client side). If you want to continue doing server side you could make an html anchor and your Read More link targets this anchor.

Answer (score 1):

At first split the string into two part. and hide the second part of the string which you wanted to show after clicking read more.

```
$string = strip_tags($body);

    if (strlen($string) > 500) {
        $stringCut = substr($string, 0, 500);
        $stringRest= substr($string, 500);
        echo '<div>'$stringCut.'<span class="string" style="display:none;">'.$stringRest.'</span>'...<a class="show">Read More</a></div>'
    }
```

and add a jquery click function to show the rest part of string.

```
$('.show').click(function(){
   $(this).parent().find('.string').show();
   $(this).hide();

});

$('.string').click(function(){
   $(this).parent().find('.show').show();
   $(this).hide();

});
```

Hope this will helps you